# amount of data returned by wcf 3.0 service contract method causes error

Tags: wcf, c#-2.0

CommuncationException was unhandled

The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

here is my svc.map file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceReference>
    <ProxyGenerationParameters
        ServiceReferenceUri="http://d3w9501/SimpleWCF/SimpleWCF.svc"
        Name="svc"
        NotifyPropertyChange="False"
        UseObservableCollection="False">
    </ProxyGenerationParameters>
    <EndPoints>
        <EndPoint
            Address="http://d3w9501.americas.hpqcorp.net/SimpleWCF/SimpleWCF.svc"
            BindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleWCF"
            Contract="TestSimpleWCF.svc.ISimpleWCF"
            >
        </EndPoint>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleWCF" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  >
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>    
    </EndPoints>
</ServiceReference>
```

Answer (score 2):

The svc.map file doesn't really help much - what we need to see to be able to help is the client side **app.config** file - that's the one that is really revelant.

Also: you need to change your client-side values in your app.config - not in your svc.map - to have any effect on your running app. Check to see whether those values are still the default 64K in your app.config - if they are, change them there!

Answer (score 0):

Located the app.config file. 
Changed maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize from 65536 to 2147483647
The message from the console client is gone now.

Thank You very much.